# C# Unable to connect to remote server (WebException, SocketException)

Tags: c#, asp.net, server, dotnet-httpclient

I try to POST some data from a website to a webservice, but i got those exceptions :

> System.AggregateException: Une ou plusieurs erreurs se sont produites. ---> 
>       System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the 
>       request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to remote server 
>       ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected 
>       party did not properly respond after a period of time or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 52.211.194.210:443
>       à System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>       à System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, 
>       Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState 
>       state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
>       --- Fin de la trace de la pile d'exception interne ---
>       à System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, 
>       TransportContext& context)
>       à System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
>        --- Fin de la trace de la pile d'exception interne ---
>       --- Fin de la trace de la pile d'exception interne ---
>       à System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean 
>       waitCompletionNotification)
>       à ldspoPunchout.ldspoPunchout.PostXMLData(String destinationUrl, String 
>         requestXml)
>         ---> (Exception interne #0) System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error 
>        occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: 
>       Impossible de se connecter au serveur distant ---> 
>       System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Une tentative de connexion a échoué car 
>       le parti connecté n’a pas répondu convenablement au-delà d’une certaine 
>       durée ou une connexion établie a échoué car l’hôte de connexion n’a pas 
>       répondu 52.211.194.210:443
>       à System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>       à System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, 
>       Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState 
>       state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
>       --- Fin de la trace de la pile d'exception interne ---
>       à System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, 
>       TransportContext& context)
>       à System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult 
>       ar)
>       --- Fin de la trace de la pile d'exception interne ---<---

my code is simple and worked out in multiple sites :

```
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestXml);
            ByteArrayContent byteArray = new ByteArrayContent(data);
            HttpResponseMessage reponse = client.PostAsync(destinationUrl, byteArray).Result;
            Stream stream = reponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            Test = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

this code use httpclient but i tried webrequest too, same issue

environment :  windows server 2012 R2 standard

i don't have access to the code of the webservice but it is a HTTPS

i'm confuse because on my local machine (windows 10) i can browse,post,get the url, even **on the server i can browse the url with IE** and it has no proxy setting

EDIT : forgot to mention that i can post on other website from the server !

i thought it was a time out but when adding those lines :

```
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Timeout.Infinite);
```

or

```
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Keep-Alive", "3600");
```

nothing change and it is rather quick(like 15sec) no matter how much time i set
and tried various other things i read :

```
              ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 
           | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
```

if someone knows where could this come from that'd be great

Thanks in advance

EDIT : i create the webrequest like this

```
                Logger.Log(xml + "                 " + url);
                var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
                PostXMLData(url, xml); 
                return url + "  :  " + Test;
```

http client is set at higher level :

```
       public static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

Comment: I would suggest that you change the line which says `byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestXml);` to `byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestXml);`. This is more robust, as it will handle all of ASCII the same way, but also the rest of UTF-8, so that if any characters that are not just basic Latin are in the XML it won't break. UTF-8 is the default encoding for XML and most web technologies.

Comment: I think in order to help you we would need to see how the Web Request is being created, i.e. how `client` is being crated, I have a feeling if you can navigate to the machine and request data through a browser there is no default Credentials being sent to the server.

Comment: yes there is no credential, they give us an url with a lifespan

Comment: Browsing to the URL is one thing, however in the code you are POSTing to it - can you post to this URL using something like fiddler or postman?

Comment: as i said yes i post to it from my computer with a c# console and postman but not from the server because i don't have full control on it maybe with a web solution i could try that !

Comment: "not from the server because i don't have full control on it "...why does that affect this, do you think? Is there a firewall? Also did you understand what Paddy meant about your request being a HTTP POST, but "browsing to the URL" uses a HTTP GET request. Does this remote URL definitely accept POST requests? What happens if you change your code to use a GET, so it's more similar to browsing to it?

Comment: Yes i understand, i found a web tool to make POST and it was success in the meantime, i had the right to use my console app on the server for testing and the post was good so this is not the server  i'm sure now, i'm now copying the website on another server for more testing,
So yes the page accept post request
Yes the server can perform POST request 
And yes to this URL, but not from the website 
So maybe it's some config issue this is where my knowledge came to fall 
I'll UPDATE when the copy of the website is ok on the other server

Comment: Problem solved it was server side and i have no further information

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, finally figured out the obstacle. It is clear that HttpClient default Port is 443 but it is Closed on Web Server.
Try to call your api Uri Address via CURL command on windows to check if this port is open or not like this :

> Curl https://api.xxx.com/api/....

if you get response by calling your address in browser be sure a proxy is set on your browser also PostMan calls the address the same way.